# Retrieving data from SPARQL result set

Tags: java, sparql, rdf, jena, owl

I've got an ontology with the objects (`NamedIndividual`) and their coordinates (X,Y) in form of `datatype` .
The individual look like this:

```xml
<owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/PredefinedOntology#Door1">
<rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/PredefinedOntology#Objects"/>
<Y rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer">20</Y>
<X rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer">33</X>
</owl:NamedIndividual>
```

I do a SPARQL query:

```sql
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
PREFIX onto: <http://www.semanticweb.org/PredefinedOntology#>

SELECT ?objects ?X ?Y
    WHERE { 
?objects rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual
; onto:X ?X
; onto:Y ?Y
 FILTER regex(str(?objects),"Door1")
}
```

My query in Eclipse is this:

```java
Model model = FileManager.get().loadModel("/home/aidos/workspace/OntologicalFramework/files/ontologies/NewOnt.owl");
String queryString = "//THE QUERY I'VE WRITTEN ABOVE IN A STRING FORM"
Query query = QueryFactory.create(queryString);
QueryExecution  qexec = QueryExecutionFactory.create(query, model);
ResultSet results = qexec.execSelect();
ResultSetFormatter.out(System.out, results, query);
```

This gives me back a result set printed to the console of my IDE, like:

```
--------------------------
| objects      | X  | Y  |
==========================
| onto:Window1 | 56 | 28 |
--------------------------
```

What I need is to get those integers 56 and 28 and store them in the `int x` and `int y` .
Could someone help me to understand how can I get them?
While debugging process I've found the `DataSetImpl` called `dataset` in the branch of `ResultSet result`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each **[ResultSet](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/arq/org/apache/jena/query/ResultSet.html)** provides access to each row as a **[QuerySolution](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/arq/org/apache/jena/query/QuerySolution.html)** through use of the [**next()**](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/arq/org/apache/jena/query/ResultSet.html#next--) method.  Then, you can use methods like **[getLiteral(String)](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/arq/org/apache/jena/query/QuerySolution.html#getLiteral-java.lang.String-)** to get the literal value of the variable with a specified name.  There are some other methods for getting variable values, too:  **get(String)** returns an **RDFNode**, and **getResource(String)** returns a **Resource**.

In this case, you could use **get()** or **getLiteral()** since the numbers are literals, and thus RDF nodes, but you can't use **getResource()**, since the numbers aren't resources (i.e., not IRIs).

Comment: Good explanation. Some additions: First, for situations where you can't be sure - for what reasoner ever - that there will be a literal or resource returned, I would suggest to use `get()` with a check whether it's a literal on the `RDFNode` object before conversion. Secondly, just to avoid problems in the case of the example code above, once you printed the resultset, you can't iterate again on it. Ah, and last but not least, Jena ARQ docs are a good point to start.